# Next JS : Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, next.js, compiler-errors

[image]

While working with Next.js in VS Code, I wanted to move a file, but I am getting this error, it used to not work, what could be the problem?